# Regex to remove numbers and others characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I would like to remove some numbers and characters from my typescript string by using regex. I think I'm close but I'm missing something.

Here the king of strings I have :

1. [15620584560] - product name (type)
2. [1256025] - product name (test+1)
3. [12560255544220] - product name

What I would like :

Product name

Here the regex I'm using.

```
product_name = product_name.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/,'');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/^\s*\[[0-9]+]\s*-\s*|\s*\([^()]*\)\s*$/g, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6yuYHl/2)

The regex matches two alternatives (separated with `|`):

- `^\s*\[[0-9]+]\s*-\s*`:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\[` - a `[`
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `]` - a `]` char
  - `\s*-\s*`  - a `-` char enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s\([^()]*\)\s*$`:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['[15620584560] - product name (type)','[1256025] - product name (test+1)','[12560255544220] - product name'];
var reg = /^\s*\[[0-9]+]\s*-\s*|\s*\([^()]*\)\s*$/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.replace(reg, ''));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I've an error when I compile :  Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: /^\s*\[[0-9]+]\s*-\s*|\s*(\([^()]*\)\s*$/: Unterminated group

Comment: @JoeAllen There was a strange `(` after `\s*`. It was not present in my regex demo. Probably, it crept into the pattern when I added `*` after `\s` manually. Sorry. I added a working code snippet.

Comment: I didn't copy the regex demo, I just copied the stackoverflow sample. Great work, it works perfectly ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One approach which might work would be to split the input string on dash, and then use a simple regex to remove all terms in parentheses:

```js
var input = '[15620584560] - product name (type)';
var fields = input.split(/\]\s*-/);
var result = fields[1].replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, '').trim();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There are tons of edge cases where this could fail.  But in the absence of such information, I'm offering this as a potential solution.

Comment: If my product name contains a "-" I want to keep it :)

Comment: @JoeAllen I updated my answer to split on `] -`, i.e. a closing bracket followed by some possible whitespace and then a hyphen.  It is doubtful that your product names would happen to have this sequence.